# Treeview (Kendo UI) with TextBox on the same page best practices in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

Let's say I have a view with Kendo treeview bounded to remote data source.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("schemas")
    .DataTextField("name")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Schemas", "Forms")))
    .Events(events => events
    .Select("onSelected")))
```

So the treeview just makes a call to the `Schemas` action in my `FormsController`

Also on the same page I have a form, which is simply the textbox and a button to submit the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Load", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{   
    <div id="rootNode">
        @Html.TextBox("rootElementName")            
        @Html.Button("next")
    </div>
}
```

So I am just wondering what is the best way to handle user input and pass it to the the `Load` action of the `FormsController`? The user should select one of the options in the treeview and enter the value into textbox.
Or should I create some sort of viewmodel for my view with all my nodes inside + two additional fields for the textbox input and selected node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take out the form elements, leaving:

```
<div id="rootNode">
    @Html.TextBox("rootElementName")            
    @Html.Button("next")
</div>
```

The following js, this will pick up the tree item id on select.
The second function will call your Form controller action with the parameters.

```
<script>
    var selectedNodeid;

    //get the tree selected item id
    function onSelected(e) {
        var data = $('#schemas).data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node);
        selectedNodeid = data.id;
    }

    //button on click event
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#next")
        .bind("click", function () {  
           //get parameters then pa
           var id = selectedNodeid;
           var rootElementName = $('#rootElementName).val()
           $.ajax({ 
             url: "Form/Load", 
             data:{id:id,rootElementName:rootElementName},
             success: function () { } 
           });
        }
     })
</script>
```

I haven't tested this but it should be close.
I look forward to someone adding a better approach.

Comment: Ok, but the how should I return and show the view from Load action?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to the view or show it as a partial in the current page?